# Async and skipping frames

Tags: android, android-asynctask

So I've run into an issue where I have an item that I click in a listview, it does a makes a few extras, and moves on the my next activity. I get an issue where my app goes to a black screen and the Console tells me

I/Choreographer: Skipped 630 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I've tried reading up on Async but I'm not sure how to use it in my code. So I'm posting my Main activity since this happens without interacting with the second activity.

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ListView ListofList;
    ArrayList<String> Lists;
    ArrayAdapter<String> ListAdapter;
    Button button;
    ArrayList<String> Subject = new ArrayList<>();
    int Size = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListofList = findViewById(R.id.LofL);
        Lists = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Lists);
        ListofList.setAdapter(ListAdapter);

        button = findViewById(R.id.AddList);
        Lists.add("Test");

        ListofList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ItemList.class);
                String s = (String) ListofList.getItemAtPosition(position);
                i.putExtra("Title", s);
                i.putExtra("size", Size);
                int a = 0;
                for (String t : Subject) {
                    i.putExtra("Item" + a, t);
                    a++;
                }
                startActivityForResult(i, 2);
            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CreateItem.class);
                String message = "Please enter the name of the list below.";
                i.putExtra("mess", message);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (data == null) {

        }
        if (data != null) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                String item = (data.getStringExtra("item"));
                Lists.add(item);
                ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == 2) {
            ArrayList<String> subject = new ArrayList<String>();
            int i = 0;
            assert data != null;
            int size = (data.getIntExtra("ListSize", 0));
            Size = size;
            while (i <= size) {
                String item = (data.getStringExtra("item" + i));
                subject.add(item);

                i++;
            }

            Subject = subject;
        }
    }


}
```

At the request of Ben P.

```html
public class ItemList extends AppCompatActivity {

    static ArrayList<String> customItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView lvItems;

    Button button;
    Button button2;

    ArrayAdapter<String> trashAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> trash;
    ListView itemtrash;
    static TextView Title;
    String Tit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);
        Title = findViewById(R.id.Title);
        //set up Item List
        customItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, customItems);
        lvItems = (ListView)  findViewById(R.id.lvItems);

        //Set up trash List
        trash = new ArrayList<String>();
        trashAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, trash);
        itemtrash = findViewById(R.id.itemtrash);

        //Initialize Buttons
        button = findViewById(R.id.AddItem);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.ClearTrash);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Title)).setText(extras.getString("Title"));
            Tit = extras.getString("Title");
            int i = 0;
            int size = (extras.getInt("size", 0));
            while (i <= size) {
                String item = (extras.getString("Item" + i));
                if (item == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                customItems.add(item);
                i++;
            }
        }

        //CharSequence Titlefilter = Title.getText();
        //lvItems.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        //ItemList.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(Titlefilter);
        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CreateItem.class);
                String message = "Please enter new item below.";
                i.putExtra("mess", message);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                trashAdapter.clear();
                trashAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        lvItems.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String s = adapter.getItem(position);
                trashAdapter.add(s);
                adapter.remove(s);
                assert s != null;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                trashAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        itemtrash.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String s = trashAdapter.getItem(position);
                customItems.add(s);
                trash.remove(s);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                trashAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        lvItems.setAdapter(adapter);
        itemtrash.setAdapter(trashAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        int a = 0;
            for (String s : customItems){
                String t = adapter.getItem(a);
                i.putExtra("item" + a, t);
                a++;
            }
        int size = customItems.size();
        i.putExtra("ListSize", size);
        setResult(2, i);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (data == null) {

        }
        if (data != null) {
            String item = (data.getStringExtra("item"));
            String title = Tit;
            customItems.add(title + "\n\n" + item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Seems pretty likely that the problem is in the second activity. Is it loading any data to display after you click on the list item?

Comment: yes give me a moment to edit it in

Comment: Hm, nothing jumps out at me (no network connection or db loading is obvious). If you comment out the whole `if (extras != null)` block, does the problem go away? Obviously you won't see your items, but this might help verify that loading the items is the slow part.

Comment: Okay so it does let me get to the ItemList Activity. It was working earlier when the items were two textviews, but I changed it to one textview to be able to use a filter. might that've been the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I accidentally made an infinite loop with while in the ItemList activity.